# How to bind textarea value in Blazor from button click?

Tags: blazor, textarea

I have a simple page as such:

```
@page "/"

<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="setTA()"/>

<textarea id="taSrc" style="margin: 0px; width: 1331px; height: 400px; visibility:visible;" @bind="taHtml" @bind:event="oninput"></textarea>

<br /><br />@taHtml

@code
{
    private string taHtml = "";
}
```

and javascript:

```
    <script>

        function setTA() {
            document.getElementById('taSrc').value = "sdsdf sdfsdfsdfdf";
        }

    </script>
```

If I type manually into the textarea, I can see the characters appear after the two break tags as expected. But not if I click the button which sets the textarea value. So the question is, why? I've also tried onchange instead of oninput.

Comment: First of all, why are you using JavaScript? This is Blazor. We don't do that here.

Comment: because I simplified what I actually need to do, get html source from an iframe. And currently, I don't know how to get the html content from an iframe server side. So javascript, I can get it, send it to a textarea, then I wanted to get it server  via the bind. But if you can tell me how to get iframe source code server side, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: You should have stated this in your question. What do you mean you can't get the HTML content? You just send a GET request... What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I can't do it with the bind? seems the easiest way, if it works

Answer (score 1):

> But not if I click the button which sets the textarea value. So the question is, why?

You are trying to jump between C# Blazor code and JS code without going through JsInterop.  And mixing JS and Blazor code on editable fields is pretty fraught with danger.

In the code you've shown you don't need any JS.  Here's a Blazor C# only working example.

```
@page "/"
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" @onclick="setTA"/>

<textarea id="taSrc" style="margin: 0px; width: 1331px; height: 400px; visibility:visible;" @bind="taHtml" @bind:event="oninput"></textarea>

<br /><br />@taHtml

@code {
    private string taHtml = "";
    private int counter = 1;

    private void setTA()
    {
        taHtml = $"Hello {counter}";
        counter++;
    }
}
```

This answers your question, but I'm guessing this isn't the whole story.  Why do you want to set the textarea in JS?

Comment: ...because what I really have is an iframe, where the page inside can be edited. So I need to then send the source code of that iframe to the server to save it as a file. No I don't really need the text area, but I was just trying to simplify what I needed to do for the post.

Comment: An Iframe is essentially a page within a page.  The only interact the Blazor outer page has is actions such as setting the `src`.  It doesn't have access to the contents.  Why are you using an IFrame?  What does it give you that you can't do with form controls?

Comment: client wants to edit their existing web pages real-time with WYSIWYG, then we need to save edited page to server

Comment: Answering that is way beyond the scope of any Stackoverflow Question!  You're on your own @E.D.

Comment: that is why I simplified it to my original post

Comment: It intrigues me - What are they actually editing in the IFrame?  How are they editing the page you are displaying in the IFrame?  Add it to the question?

Comment: just a 3rd party WYSIWYG